# How to speed up a Wordle backtesting function to run 13,000 words in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to find the most optimal Wordle starter word. I created a function to determine how good a starter was by seeing how many words it would eliminate from a 13,000 word list.

For example, if my starter word was PLANE, I want to eliminate every single word from the dataset that contains the letters 'P','L','A','N', or 'E'. From that, I would see what % of words it eliminated and the word with the highest % would be the optimal starter word.

So suppose you ran `backtest(starter="plane")` it would return `('plane', '87.37%')` .

I am trying to run all 13,000 possible wordle words through the backtester but it's taking way too long on Python. How can I speed this up?

**Creating List**

```
words = []
with open('list.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        words.append(line.strip())
```

**Function**

```
def backtest(starter):

    # list creation portion
    words = []
    with open('list.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            words.append(line.strip())
    total = len(words)


    guess = starter
    result = "#####"
    
    tupleX = tuple(words)
    for word in tupleX:
        for i in range(5):
            
            if result[i] == "#" and guess[i] in word:
                words.remove(word)
                break
    
    pct = round(100 - (len(words)/total*100), 2)
    return guess, ("{}%".format(pct))
```

**Backtest and append to dataframe**

```
import pandas as pd

data = []

for i in words:
    hold = backtest(starter=i)
    data.append(hold)

bruteForce = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Word','Score'])
bruteForce = bruteForce.sort_values(by=['Score'], ascending=False)
bruteForce
```

I attempted removing the list creation portion from the backtesting function, but if I do that, it alters the original word list. When researching solutions, I came across multi-threading (which seems slightly too advanced for me, although I'm willing to give it a try) but I was wondering if anyone had any alternatives that I could attempt?

Comment: Not what you are after but did you know you can guess the Wordle word by Python?: https://medium.com/p/ce33ee0e3330

Comment: @gtomer Yeah! I actually made a Wordle solver before trying to find the optimal starter word. It involved a similar strategy to what I'm using here: I'd type in a random word and use the feedback I got from Wordle to eliminate words from the dataset until I was left with the answer. I'll make sure to check out this article though, thanks :)

Comment: The Medium article I wrote is guessing the right word without any guesses....

Comment: @gtomer Just read through it. Really creative idea to use Google Search trends haha, I never would've thought of that! Seems like it's really effective too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your biggest performance issues here is removing elements from `words` in backtest. It leads to Python reallocating memory for the now shorter list. You do not need to remove those elements at all, you only use this list to get its length. Thus, you can very significantly improve the performance of your algorithm by keeping track of how many words didn't fit by simply incrementing an integer rather than modifying a list. Then, when you return the result, you can use `len(words) - removed`, where `removed` is this integer. This can probably speed up the whole process more then 10x!

Not modifying the list also allows you to only load the list once from the file, which also speeds things up, althought not as significantly as the first change. Also, is there any use for the `result` variable? You could remove it (along with the always truthy check of `result[i] == "#"`) and also get a tiny performance boost.

I made small changes to your code to address these issues with really big effects. It is definitely not the most optimal you can get, but it should finish within minutes and doesn't require any changes in the main idea of the algorithm.

```py
def backtest(starter, words):
    total = len(words)

    guess = starter
    result = "#####"
    
    # track how many words your algorith would remove
    removed = 0
    
    for word in words:
        for i in range(5):
            if result[i] == "#" and guess[i] in word:
                # instead of actually removing, increment this
                removed += 1
                break
    
    pct = round(100 - ((total - removed)/total*100), 2)
    return guess, ("{}%".format(pct))
```

main:

```py
import pandas as pd
import time   # just to measure how long it runs

data = []
words = []
with open('list.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        words.append(line.strip())

start = time.perf_counter()
j = 1

for i in words:
    hold = backtest(starter=i, words=words)
    data.append(hold)
    # just so you can see progress and timing
    if not j % 100:
        print(j, ": ", time.perf_counter() - start)
    j += 1

bruteForce = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Word','Score'])
bruteForce = bruteForce.sort_values(by=['Score'], ascending=False)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Filip! I just implemented this back into the project and it works perfectly! Also really appreciate your detailed explanation of where my initial method went wrong. I'll definitely look into your recommendations of how to improve my code. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

To calculate elimination rates you can use built-in `set` data structure (please note, that Python 3.9+ is required for the used typing manner):

```
def read_words(path: str) -> list[str]
    """Read words to the list"""
    with open(path) as file:
        return file.read().splitlines()
        

def calculate_elimination_rates(words: list[str]) -> dict[str, float]:
    """Calculate elimination rate for each word"""
    # "-1" because we don't count the word itself
    words_number = len(words) - 1
    # Transform the list of words to the list of letters
    words_letters = [set(word) for word in words]

    # Elimination rates
    rates = {}

    for word in words:
        current_letters = set(word)
    
        rates[word] = (sum(
            1 for letters in words_letters 
            if len(letters - current_letters) == 0
        ) - 1) / words_number
    
    return rates


def main() -> None:
    words = read_words("list.txt")
    rates = calculate_elimination_rates(words)
    print(rates)
```

P.S. You example is slow not only because the used algorithm is slow itself, but also because each call of `backtest` reads data from harddrive.

Comment: This doesn't seem to produce correct results.

Comment: Hey, just tried this out and it definitely sped up the program but the  program isn't outputting out the correct results. I'm trying to tweak it a little bit (I assume the problem is with the rates calculation) and will get back to you if I manage to get it to product the right answers. Appreciate the explanation on why my method didn't work out!

Comment: @StayShmacked, in my example I assume that we want to calculate rates for the list where the current word is excluded. Probably, this makes difference. You can just delete “- 1” in lines 10 and 23. I think then you will see desired result. Please, let me know if so